# Can't sign in on Visual Studio 2017 Community but can for 2013 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-community

I can't sign in to Visual Studio Community 2017 but I can sign in to Visual Studio Professional 2013. This is on my work network; I can sign in fine from my home network on both.

They are both using the same login screen and the credentials are correct, however, in 2017 I get the following error every time:

[image]

"Sorry, we ran into a problem.
An error has occurred and we can no longer retrieve information for your account. Please reenter your credentials."

What is the difference between signing in on 2013 vs 2017?